Can't load files on Artifactory via jfrog
I really need some suggestions about this problem.
Artifactory OSS version 7.77.5 running on a Mac in docker.
I installed and run with this :
docker run --name artifactory -v artifactory_data:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:7.77.5
Created users/repo/etc. and I can login via UI, load artifacts, see them, etc.
Everything seems working.
However I can't upload anything using jfrog.
Also as admin I obtain :
[Error] server response: 403 Forbidden
Forbidden
Looking the log on Artifactory on docker I got :
[jffe ] [WARN ] [] [frontend-service.log] [main                ] - Request blocked by CSRF protection, missing XHR header, blocked url : "/login/artifactory/api/security/token"
I'm using jfrog (jf) vs 2.63.0 on a Ubuntu 22.04 to try to upload something, using a security token (jf config) to access the server.
This an example of loading :
jf rt u "test.txt"  testrepo --server-id=cctest
There is some solution to this problem ?
Thanks

I don't have the exact answer as there is too many variables here. But I can try to help show you steps to debug it.
Can you install the JFrog CLI locally on your Mac. Can you make an upload from there?
Can you upload a file directly in the UI?
Can you upload a file using curl? from your Mac? From the Ubuntu machine?
Doing these different tests might help you see where the issue lies exactly.
Is the Ubuntu machine having to go through some network proxies?
You can read about such a problem here: https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-how-to-fix-the-error-csrferror-no-xhr-header/overview
The error you shared is from the Frontend log specifically [jffe], it is just a warning and may not be showing the full picture of the problem. You can exec into the container and go to the /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log directory (or into the volume in your Mac) and look at the artifactory-service.log, and artifactory-request.log at the time of the failure. They might give more information.

Thanks !!
Yes, also accessing from the mac via jfrog fails with the same error.
Via UI no problem though, from the Mac or via the Ubuntu machine.
It must related then on the way I put the Artifactory visible online.
I'll try with curl when I have time to experiment, need to find a different solution fast.
Thanks !
